# Unable to read HiveServer2 configs from ZooKeeper

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, kylin

I use HDP3.1. And I Ambari to deploy hadoop cluster and hive. After deployed, I can run hive in shell successfully. And then I deploy Apache Kylin2.6, it can sync hive table. But when I build the cube, I got the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: OS command error exit with return code: 1, error message: SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://datacenter1:2181,datacenter2:2181,datacenter3:2181/default;password=hdfs;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;user=hdfs;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2
19/02/15 10:04:53 [main]: INFO jdbc.HiveConnection: Connected to datacenter3:10000
19/02/15 10:04:53 [main]: WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to datacenter3:10000
19/02/15 10:04:53 [main]: ERROR jdbc.Utils: Unable to read HiveServer2 configs from ZooKeeper
Error: Could not open client transport for any of the Server URI's in ZooKeeper: Failed to open new session: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot modify dfs.replication at runtime. It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime (state=08S01,code=0)
Cannot run commands specified using -e. No current connection
The command is: 
hive -e "USE default;
```

I run hive command in shell. It's success. The connection string is same as the string when run build cube in kylin. I'm confused why it is success in shell but failed in building cube.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://datacenter1:2181,datacenter2:2181,datacenter3:2181/default;password=hdfs;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;user=hdfs;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2
19/02/15 12:10:19 [main]: INFO jdbc.HiveConnection: Connected to datacenter3:10000
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
Beeline version 3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78 by Apache Hive
0: jdbc:hive2://datacenter1:2181,datacenter2:>
```

Comment: It seems like multiple slf4j binding creating a problem for you, please delete one and try.

Comment: I removed one slf4j jar. The problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add these two properties to hive-site.xml.

```
<property>
  <name>hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist</name>
  <value>mapred.*|hive.*|mapreduce.*|spark.*</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist.append</name>
  <value>mapred.*|hive.*|mapreduce.*|spark.*</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the root cause. There is 'Cannot modify dfs.replication at runtime.' error message in the error log. Kylin set this property in `$KYLIN_HOME/conf/kylin_hive_conf.xml`. And when it is running hive command, it will auto append the properties in that file. The final command likes: `hive --hiveconf dfs.replication=2 ..........`
It looks like that dfs.replication property can't be appened to hive command. I removed this property in `kylin_hive_conf.xml`. And it works now.